# Python install mysqlclient keeps on giving error

Tags: python, mysql, 20.04

From a list of the following dependencies present in a requirements.txt file

```
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.4.1
colorama==0.4.3
Django==3.0.6
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
mysqlclient==1.4.6
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.5.2
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1
wrapt==1.12.1
```

when I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

keep on getting the following error

[image: Error installing mysqlclient]

If I follow [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41458329/5675325) by removing `mysqlclient==1.4.6` from the requirements.txt file and try

```
sudo apt-get install mysqlclient
```

I get

> E: Unable to locate package mysqlclient

Comment: The package is called `mysql-client`, with an `-`.

Comment: Are we speaking of the same one @Jos? (https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Comment: Ah this is very confusing. I didn't know that Python could install its own MySQL client. Once you start using `apt-get install` you would need `mysql-client`.

Comment: Got it @Jos, thanks for pointing that out. Already managed to solve it installing some dependencies and before installing requirements.txt and that worked fine. This way is convenient for me because it makes the work between people using Ubuntu and people using W10 smoother (they'll use the same requirements.txt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fix it, I had to run first

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and only then install the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it was some silly issue related to `gcc`.

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

The above command should fix everything.